# $r$ power of positive increasing sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $(c_j, j\in\mathbb{N})$ be a positive increasing sequences convergent to $\infty$, ie. 
$c_1\le c_2\le\cdots\le c_j$ and $\lim_{j\to\infty}c_j=\infty$.

Let $r\in [1,\infty).$

Does $(c_j^r,j\in\mathbb{N})$ converge? Why?

Comment: Write down the what it means for $(c_j)$ to converge to $\infty$. The proof then should fall out.

Comment: $c_j$ bounds $c_j^r$ below so the result should be obvious.

Comment: $c_j^r\ge c_j$, but $c_j\to\infty$, how can I say $$c_j^r$ is convergent as the lower bound not even convergent?

Comment: The sequence $(a_j)$ converges to $\infty$ if for any $B$ there is an $N$ such that $a_n\gt B$ for every $n\gt N$.

Comment: when I see $\infty$, I just cannot accept the term "convergent". Could you please provide a detail answer for the question I asked. I am easily get misunderstood by reading comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for each $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $a_n>M$, we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$.

So if $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n=\infty$, given $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $c_n>M^{-r}$. Hence $n\geqslant N$ implies $c_n^r>M$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n^r=\infty$.

Alternatively, we may note that the map $x\mapsto x^r$ is continuous and nondecreasing for $r>0$, so it follows immediately that $c_n^r$ is convergent.